# Mercurial - untracked file differs

Tags: eclipse, mercurial

My problem is I got this error message when I try pulling repository from mercurial.

[image]

Why?

Comment: This is a mercurial, not worklight question.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Mercurial: "untracked file in working directory differs from file in requested revision"?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4822129/mercurial-untracked-file-in-working-directory-differs-from-file-in-requested-r)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I already found the answer. I need to update after pull.

[image]